# SQL Server 2014 Error

Tags: sql-server

I've just created a new DB and added a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Dump] 
(
  ID                    int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  itemId                nvarchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  title                 nvarchar(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  lType                 nvarchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  startTime             datetime NOT NULL,
  endTime               datetime NOT NULL,
  currency              nvarchar(5) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  price                 money NOT NULL,
  condition             nvarchar(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  category              int NULL,
  category2             nvarchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  P_URL                     nvarchar(250) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  seller                nvarchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  Position              int NULL,
  TS                    datetime2(7) NULL,
  quantity              bigint NULL,
  category3             nvarchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  bestO                 bit NULL,
  Duration              nvarchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  pFBP                  smallmoney NULL,
  postalCode            nvarchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS NULL,
  country               nvarchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS NULL,
  location              nvarchar(60) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS NULL,
  isMulti               varchar(5) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS NULL,

  CONSTRAINT Dump_pk 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
              STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Then I filled in the above table with some 25 million records from another DB
using a query like this

```
INSERT INTO G.dbo.[Dump] (itemId, title, lType, startTime, endTime, currency, price, condition, category, category2, P_URL, seller, Position, TS, quantity, category3, bestO, Duration, pFBP, postalCode, country, location, isMulti)
    SELECT 
        itemId, title, lType, startTime, endTime, currency, price, 
        condition, category, category2, P_URL, seller, Position, TS, 
        quantity, category3, bestO, Duration, pFBP, postalCode, country, 
        location, isMulti 
    FROM 
        Global.dbo.[Dump]
```

It took some 15 minutes but.. it succeeded

Since I had some other 45 million in another table I tried to add these 45 million to the same table and I changed only the FROM parameter in above query

```
INSERT INTO G.dbo.[Dump] (itemId, title, lType, startTime, endTime, currency, price, condition, category, category2, P_URL, seller, Position, TS, quantity, category3, bestO, Duration, pFBP, postalCode, country, location, isMulti)
    SELECT 
        itemId, title, lType, startTime, endTime, currency, price, 
        condition, category, category2, P_URL, seller, Position, TS, 
        quantity, category3, bestO, Duration, pFBP, postalCode, country, 
        location, isMulti 
    FROM 
        Global.dbo.[Dump_EU]
```

but after some 70 minutes I got this:

> Msg 1105, Level 17, State 2, Line 3
>   Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.Dump'.'Dump_pk' in database 'G' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

The DB file with the 25 million records is some 10GB and on the HD there are more than 60 GB free.

There is no size limit both to the data file and to the log file

What can cause the error?

Comment: from the error message, I think you have not enabled Auto Growth on your database's Primary file.

Comment: @jpw in case of Express SQL you get a very unique error saying something `your license limit is 10240 MB per database` etc. I think the issue here is the Auto-growth setting on the primary file.

Comment: @M.Ali No, 'unfortunately'  AutoGrowth is enabled and Unlimited both on Data and Log :-(, and is not Express edition therefore does not have 10GB limit

Comment: What about your `tempdb` DB? Is it OK?

Comment: @gofr1, yes `tempdb` is OK, I 'solved' removing indexes and then rebuild it, although it takes a lot of time... :-(, but I assume it is due to lack of space: next time will try increasing HD/SSD free space